# Proving linear independence.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ be a $3$-dimensional vector space over the field of rational numbers. Suppose $T$ is a linear operator and $T(x)=y$, $T(y)=z$, $T(z)=x+y$ for certain $x$, $y$, $z$ in $E$ and $x\ne 0$. Prove that $x, y, z$ are linearly independent.

Comment: what about $x=y=z=0$?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein- thank you for the correction.

Comment: @user61062: Please show your working in future. It helps us identify where you're having trouble, assures us that you're actually trying to understand, etc :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the linear map $\pi:\Bbb Q^3\to E$ sending $e_1\mapsto x$, $e_2\mapsto y$ and $e_3\mapsto z$, and the linear operator $\phi:\Bbb Q^3\to\Bbb Q^3$ with matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
in the standard basis. Then the information about $T$ says that $T\circ\pi=\pi\circ\phi$. This implies that $\ker\pi$ is a $\phi$-stable subspace. But the minimal polynomal $X^3-X-1$ of $\phi$ is irreducible over$~\Bbb Q$ (by the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)) so the only $\phi$-stable subspaces of are those of dimensions $0$ and $3$. But since $x\neq0$ one has $\ker\pi\neq\Bbb Q^3$, so $\pi$ is an isomorphism, and $x,y,z$ linearly independent.